# How to download a google drive folder using link in linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, curl, wget, gdrive

I have a shared google drive folder link(Anyone on the internet with this link can view) as below
Ex: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i_c8LhSLf-LttV-UOMDcY4rLAalxxxx?usp=sharing

I want to download using any of the wget/CURL/any python packages.

I have tried the below and it doesn't work.

```
 curl -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1i_c8LhSLf-LttV-UOMDcY4rLAalkcayn&export=download" > test.tar.gz
```

```
import gdown
import time
url='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1i_c8LhSLf-LttV-UOMDcY4rLAalkxxxx'
output='/data/test/test.zip'
time.sleep(100)
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
```

Error:

```
Permission denied: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1i_c8LhSLf-LttV-UOMDcY4rLAalkcayn
Maybe you need to change permission over 'Anyone with the link'?
```

The below command worked for files but not for folders

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11e85AnMEGEjrxPuewlmeg-ABOZ8asdf' -O test
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: For example, in your situation, this CLI tool is useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/goodls#downloadfilesfromfolder

Answer (score 7):

### Update:

Now folder download functional is in main [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown) package, so simply do the following

1. install via pip

```sh
pip install gdown
```

2. use it in python:

```
import gdown
gdown.download_folder(url, quiet=True)
```

## Using *"gdown"*

**gdown** is a great application to download single file from gdrive with only file id or link required, **but** there were several great minds of github who were inspired to implement a folder download functionality.

Actually, state of this feature can be viewed in [gdown:90 github PR](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/pull/90).

You can use it, since it is implemented almost perfectly (there is an issue of **only 50 files** in folder **as maximum** to download):

1. install gdown with developed `folder_download` feature via pip:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/giuliano-oliveira/gdown_folder.git
```

2. Now we need to run `gdown.download_folder` function in python3 shell (since cli support for folder download is not implemented):

`$ python3`

```py
import gdown
gdown.download_folder(gdrive_folder_link, quiet=True)
```

Use your own `gdrive_folder_link` in string format `'https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/{id}'` (others weren't checked).

**Note:**

- You might be required to signup to gdown application.
- Also, remember about maximum downloaded elements from folder is 50, since there is internal problems with acquiring relevant information about all items via gdrive request API.
- You might be required to create the target folder name

Comment: I get syntax error for ` gdown.download_folder` This was my command ` gdown.download_folder(https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/18EunmjOJsbE5Lh9zA0cZ4wKV6Um46dkg, quiet=True)`

Comment: @Sulphur, syntax error means incorrect typing, etc. You should use `str` type for gdrive folder link. (embrace your link in quotes)

Comment: [Unless the files do not have fully public permissions](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/issues/29), I guess

Comment: great, but no auth support